# Why does ActiveDirectory authentication using .Net DirectoryServices work for all but one user?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm using the following C#/.Net code on Windows(7/2008/etc) to authenticate users against active directory:

```
DirectoryEntry entry =
    new DirectoryEntry(domainPath, domain + @"\" + username, password);
object obj = entry.NativeObject;
```

This works for hundreds of users, but not for one. I suspect it's something in the active directory account setup. The user has no problem authenticating on Windows with the exact same credentials or accessing network resources using windows integrated authentication. The user is a sys admin and is also set up as a remote admin.

Comment: what is that username/password, maybe it contains a character that cause problem for your program!

Comment: Also, have you confirmed the value you're getting for `domainPath` is correct for this user?  Could be that this user is in a different container than your other users since they're an admin.

Comment: Good question. I wrote a simple console test app using the same core code that passes the credentials directly to the DirectoryEntry call without any kind of modification and had the user run it. They still have the same problem. The app also echoes the credentials that were input so the user can verify that the credentials are not being altered.

Comment: Are you getting an exception / error message?

Comment: It would be useful to see what exception you're getting.  Does this code work for other sys admins as well?  Perhaps you're using a sys admin account that is denied password replication and you're attempting to authenticate against a read-only domain controller?

Comment: The exception I'm getting is System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: Can you give us the LDP view of your special user ?

Comment: Have you tried the other API?
`PrincipalContext _pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

_pContext.ValidateCredentials(string user, string pass);`
The error messages are often times more useful.